# How to use ant design in server side rendering?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to use ant design in server side rendering react application project. How to import antd in server side rendering ?

```
import {
  Icon, Form, Input, Button, Upload, Select, Badge,
  Avatar, Divider, Checkbox, DatePicker, Row, Col, Carousel 
} from 'antd';
```

Answer (score 0):

**As per new Documentation**
The support for SSR (server-side rendering) is still in the initial stage.

**Next.js**

Using antd-mobile in Next.js requires some additional configuration.

**Next.js 12**

First, you need to install next-transpile-modules:

```
$ npm install --save-dev next-transpile-modules
# or
$ yarn add -D next-transpile-modules
# or
$ pnpm add -D next-transpile-modules
```

Then configure it in next.config.js:

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([
  'antd-mobile',
]);

module.exports = withTM({
  // other Next.js configuration in your project
});
```

**Next.js 13**

Next.js 13 can automatically transpile and bundle dependencies from external dependencies (node_modules). This replaces the next-transpile-modules package.

```
    // next.config.js
    const nextConfig = {
      transpilePackages: ['antd-mobile'],
    };

    module.exports = nextConfig;
```

To use antd-mobile in app directory, add the 'use client' directive at the top of the file.

```
// app/page.jsx
'use client'

import { Button } from 'antd-mobile'
```

Please checkout the below page for more details
https://mobile.ant.design/guide/ssr/

Answer (score -1):

Check next.js example with ant-design: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-ant-design

Comment: I'm not sure how it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can just import css from local path if you have or using cdn

`<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/antd/3.11.2/antd.css">`

with imports nothing changes

Edit:

if you want to override some less variables i am using lessc and build css from ant less, so in package.json is script

```
"build:antd": "lessc --js --modify-var=@layout-body-background=#ffffff ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.less > dist/ant.css",
```

and run it:

```
npm run build:antd
```

then import this css in html

Comment: This is very unoptimized when you use import wiht ant design if you use a babel or typescript plugin (like tsImportPluginFactory for typescript) it loads only the CSS that is required by the components you import.

Comment: I'm upvoting this solution because it works when using ant.design with React server-side rendering on Cloudflare Workers which can't use `eval`. The only thing I would change is switch to the minified version. Just change `antd.css` to `antd.min.css`. Also, `3.11.2` can be changed to the current version which is `4.9.1` as of this writing.